# JavaScript Array.prototype.splice() Usage

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to write a function that removes a certain number of elements from an array based on an input.  As you can see in the code below I am opting to splice the array to return a new array.  I read about this at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Here is the code that I have right now:

```
function slasher(arr, howMany) {


  var newArray = arr.splice(0, howMany);

  return newArray;
}

slasher([1, 2, 3], 2);
```

However, the console gives me the output on testing of [1, 2].

I was expecting an output of [3] based on the documentation I read at Mozilla.

UPDATE: After reading the comments I realize that I misunderstood what splice() actually accomplishes.

Comment: *"I was expecting an output of [3] based on the documentation I read at Mozilla."* Have a look at the documentation again. It clearly says what `.splice` does and what it returns: *"Return value: An array containing the deleted elements."* You deleted `1` and `2`, hence you get `[1, 2]` as return value. Where did you read that it returns a new array with the kept elements?

Comment: Return original array `return arr`. `var newArray =` is not necessary.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks, I did read the documentation but I misunderstood.  They gave an example that made it seem like what I was expecting would happen. When I changed the code to return arr; it worked.  THanks.

Comment: Remember that `.splice()` returns what it removes, but alters the original Array. If you don't want to affect the original Array, use `.slice()`, although it takes an index rather than a count. `.slice()` just returns the slice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve the output you were expecting you have to modify your code slightly.

The `.splice()` function returns the removed elements as you can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

To get the behavior you were expecting you modify your code like this:

```
function slasher(arr, howMany) {
  arr.splice(0, howMany);
  return arr;
}

slasher([1, 2, 3], 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

`splice` will return the elements that were removed from the array, while the original array will be modified.

Comment: I realize that now. The documentation was worded in a way that I misread what was going on within an example.

Answer (score 0):

After reading comments I realized my error. If you change the output return request to

```
return arr;
```

the code works just fine.

The full working code is:

```
function slasher(arr, howMany) {


  var newArray = arr.splice(0, howMany);

  return arr;
}
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that you are returning the original array, not a new array.

Comment: there is no need for a new variable declaration. you can work on the array you get as an argument as you can see in my solution.

Comment: When I removed the new var it no longer functioned correctly.